# Parsing a piece of data to get id and email in one shot

Tags: awk, grep

I need some suggestion on if this can be done..I have following data(this is just one line,there will be blocks of such lines) coming out after running a command,is there a way I can use grep and awk and parse each line to get the number and owner email in one shot like below

```
Output:-

12345 mbarry@int.qualcomm.com

Input:-
change I5e55796844350e543f8460c53ec6e755ebe663d4
  project: platform/vendor/company-proprietary/chip
  branch: master
  id: I5e55796844350e543f8460c53ec6e755ebe663d4
  number: 12345
  subject: chip: changes to tl logging structure
  owner:
    name: Gord barry
    email: mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
    username: mbarry
  url: https://review-android.quicinc.com/12345
  commitMessage: chip: changes to tl logging structure

                 The existing TL logging has been divided into three distinct modules:
                 TL_BA (14), TL_HO (13) and TL (existing module). Thus the log with
                 loglevel 5 in file chip_qct_tl_hostsupport.c can be viewed by issuing
                 the following command - iwpriv chip0 setchipdbg 13 5 1.

                 Change-Id: I5e55796844350e543f8460c53ec6e755ebe663d4
  createdOn: 2012-08-09 15:40:57 PDT
  lastUpdated: 2012-08-21 16:43:08 PDT
  sortKey: 001f390f00023ead
  open: true
  status: NEW
  currentPatchSet:
    number: 3
    revision: 922872178946a712ab9f04483bc93216573cec6e
    parents:
 [ae259408e6ab530be62e02fdeafef34834d68709]
    ref: refs/changes/17/12345/3
    uploader:
      name: Gord barry
      email: mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
      username: mbarry
    createdOn: 2012-08-21 16:43:08 PDT
    files:
      file: /COMMIT_MSG
      type: ADDED
    files:
      file: rich/CORE/TL/inc/tlDebug.h
      type: MODIFIED
    files:
      file: rich/CORE/TL/inc/chip_qct_tl.h
      type: MODIFIED
    files:
      file: rich/CORE/TL/src/chip_qct_tl.c
      type: MODIFIED
    files:
      file: rich/CORE/TL/src/chip_qct_tl_ba.c
      type: MODIFIED
    files:
      file: rich/CORE/TL/src/chip_qct_tl_hosupport.c
      type: MODIFIED
    files:
      file: rich/CORE/VOSS/inc/vos_types.h
      type: MODIFIED
    files:
      file: rich/CORE/VOSS/src/vos_trace.c
      type: MODIFIED
    files:
      file: rich/CORE/WDA/src/chip_qct_wda_ds.c
      type: MODIFIED
    files:
      file: rich/CORE/WDI/TRP/DTS/src/chip_qct_wdi_dts.c
      type: MODIFIED
```

Comment: If it is all on one line, how is it delimited?

Comment: @Thor -there is a one -line space after changeid

Comment: wrt "is there a way I can use **grep and** awk..." - you don't need grep if you're using awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `grep` in one shot:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=(email|umber): )\S+' file
12345 
mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
3 
mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
```

Use `xargs -n2` to get both on one line:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=(email|umber): )\S+' file | xargs -n2
12345 mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
3 mbarry@int.qualcomm.com

$ grep -Po '(?<=(email|umber): )\S+' tfile | paste - -
12345   mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
3       mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
```

Explanation:

This is [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `'(?<=a)b'` that matches `b` followed by `a`. In your case you want to match the the string following `email:` or `number:` however positive look behinds have to be fixed length so we have to drop the `n` in number. `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace character.

```
(?<=   # Positive lookbehind 
(      # Group for alternation
email  # Literal string email
|      # Alternation (or)
umber  # Literal string umber
)      # Close 
:      # : Literal colon and single space 
)      # Close positive lookbehind 
\S+    # One or more non-whitespace character
```

---

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F: '/email|number/{print $2}' file | xargs -n2
12345 mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
3 mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
```

Comment: Or `paste - -` for merging. +1.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that you need GNU grep for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]:]+' '{a[$2]=$3} END{ print a["number"], a["email"] }' file
awk -F'[[:space:]:]+' '{a[$2]=$3} /email:/{ print a["number"], a["email"] }' file
awk -F'[[:space:]:]+' '{a[$2]=$3} /email:/{ print a["number"], a["email"]; exit }' file
```

and if neither of those is what you're looking for then provide more details on what it IS you're looking for.

Here's how the last script above works for me with the posted sample input:

```
$ head -15 file
change I5e55796844350e543f8460c53ec6e755ebe663d4
  project: platform/vendor/company-proprietary/chip
  branch: master
  id: I5e55796844350e543f8460c53ec6e755ebe663d4
  number: 12345
  subject: chip: changes to tl logging structure
  owner:
    name: Gord barry
    email: mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
    username: mbarry
  url: https://review-android.quicinc.com/12345
  commitMessage: chip: changes to tl logging structure

                 The existing TL logging has been divided into three distinct modules:
                 TL_BA (14), TL_HO (13) and TL (existing module). Thus the log with

$ awk -F'[[:space:]:]+' '{a[$2]=$3} /email:/{ print a["number"], a["email"]; exit }' file
12345 mbarry@int.qualcomm.com
```